# Error "El programa '[7304] iisexpress.exe' terminó con código 0 (0x0)." al iniciar depuración

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

LLevo unos días trabajando en un proyecto de `Visual Studio`, con `ASP.NET`.

Hasta ayer funcionaba sin problemas, pero desde ayer a última hora de la tarde me aparece este error cada vez que inicio la depuración.

> ```
> El programa '[7304] iisexpress.exe' terminó con código 0 (0x0).
> ```

He buscado en google y probado a reinstalar todo, pero sigue igual.

La versión que estoy utilizando es `Visual Studio 2015` y el S.O. `Windows 10`

Comment: Has visto [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19472682/579895)?

Comment: Si, no dio resultado.

Comment: Ninguna de las respuestas que hay? Entonces lamentablemente es complicado ayudarte, ya que es un problema que no podemos reproducir :(

Comment: La respuesta que mejor funcionó fue la de cambiar el puerto, no me daba ese error, pero no terminaba de cargar la pantalla.

Comment: Si es un proyecto personal, intenta instalar el Visual Studio 2017 a ver si así solucionas el problema. Como te digo, es difícil darte alguna solución ya que no podemos reproducir el problema en nuestros equipos

Comment: Lo sé, estuve leyendo y es como le venga al programa. No es un proyecto personal, así que tendré que esperar a ver lo que dice mi superior. Gracias de todas formas por tu tiempo.